# How to set value of dropdown in state variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Set only one value from whole dropdown list to the state variable.
Here in this code there's some issue and due to that the proper value is not getting stored in state variable qualification.

Please give solution in terms of name context only. Not in ref...
Solution is as follows:

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {qualification:''};
    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);
  }
  submitData(event)
  {

  }
  inputData(event)
  {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
        <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-ch dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Qualification
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-ch dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Gynaec" onChange={this.inputData} name="qualification">Gynaec</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Medicine" onChange={this.inputData} name="qualification">Medicine</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Surgery" onChange={this.inputData} name="qualification">Surgery</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Question: why are there 3 buttons with class ```dropdown-item```?

Comment: It’s bootstrap...! And there it’s defined in such way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes required in question is we have to change the event which we are passing in the every button.

Do changes like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {qualification:''};
    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);
  }
  submitData(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.qualification)
  }
  inputData(event)
  {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
        <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-ch dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Qualification
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-ch dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Gynaec" onClick={this.inputData} name="qualification">Gynaec</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Medicine" onClick={this.inputData} name="qualification">Medicine</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Surgery" onClick={this.inputData} name="qualification">Surgery</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Change code to onClick event in every button. And pass the console to see that correct output is shown or not!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** For `<button />`, you should use `onClick` rather than `onChange`.

What is the error that you are seeing?
I have a feeling your error is in your `inputData` handler.

`event.target.name` seems to be either `Gynaec`, `Medicine`, or `Surgery`.
`event.target.value` seems to always be `qualification`.

Should the logic be flipped? Like so?

```
  inputData(event)
  {
    this.setState({[event.target.value]: event.target.name});
  }
```

Also, the `console.log` that you have after `setState` won't print what you expect it to. `setState` is asynchronous ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)). If you want to run code after `setState` is completed, you can pass a callback function as the second argument of `setState`.

```
this.setState({ foo: "SOME NEW STATE" }, () => {
    console.log("This runs after setState has completed!");  
});
```

Comment: No logic is correct, because I’ve some other file in which this logic is correct for simple input field... but for dropdown I’m not getting....

Comment: Oh, it might be a typo. I noticed that you have `onChange` on your `<button />`. Can you change it to `onClick`?

Comment: this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    .then(console.log(this.state.qualification) );

Comment: Is above comment way is correct way for .then() method?